# problem installing sbpl from source in ROS Indigo

Tags: ros, sbpl-lattice-planner, sbpl, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to install [sbpl](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl) from [source](https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl/tree/master) because I have to make some changes to the CMakeLists.txt file so that it works on my ARM Processor Single board computer (see [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/217240/running-sbpl_lattice_planner-on-nvidia-jetson-tk1/)). While installing sbpl from source, I ran following commands (from catkin_ws/src/) :

```
git clone https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl.git   
cd sbpl   
mkdir build   
cd build   
cmake ..   
make   
sudo make install
```

All the commands ran successfully but when I do `roscd sbpl` after it, the output is :
`roscd: No such package/stack 'sbpl'`.

**Update:**
Also, I tried installing and using SBPL as a ROS package but that does not seem to be working:

```
git clone https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl.git  
rosmake sbpl # sbpl is in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

but I get the following output:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['sbpl']                                    
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/naman/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20150908-105307
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['sbpl'] to:
[]                                       
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['sbpl']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

Does anyone have any idea why is it still not able to find sbpl and what am I doing wrong?

**Update 2:**
So, I tried installing sbpl as a CMake Package (as mentioned above) and tried using it as a system dependency as suggested in the answer. When I do `catkin_make` in catkin_ws/ to build the [sbpl_lattice_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl_lattice_planner), I get the following error:

```
[ 97%] make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libsbpl.so', needed by `/home/naman/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsbpl_lattice_planner.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [dr_sbpl_planner/sbpl_lattice_planner/CMakeFiles/sbpl_lattice_planner.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

It looks like sbpl_lattice_planner is not able to find the necessary sbpl library and is throwing an error and hence its not able to run.

**Update 3:**
@gvdhoorn: I am using the fork you mentioned. My PKG_CONFIG_PATH is:

```
/home/naman/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/home/naman/catkin_ws/devel/lib/x86_64-linux gnu/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig
```

Therefore, sbpl_lattice_planner looks for `libsbpl.so` in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib` and is not able to find it.
Once, I build sbpl as mentioned above, it installs `libsbpl.so` in `/usr/local/lib` and `sbpl.pc` in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` but its not in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH and therefore its not able to find the required files BUT even if I add `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` to PKG_CONFIG_PATH, it still looks for the file in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib` and hence gives the same error as mentioned above which is really confusing for me.

Just to check, I also tried copying `libsbpl.so` and `sbpl.pc` to `/home/naman/catkin_ws/devel/lib/` and  `/home/naman/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig` respectively but again it always looks at `/opt/ros/indigo/lib` and throws an error.

And yeah, If I copy files to `/opt/ros/indigo/lib` and `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig`, it works without any error!

**Update 4:**

> Why did you link to the original sbpl
> repository then in your question?

That was my mistake, sorry about that! I am using [tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/sbpl_lattice_planner) fork.

The output of `pkg-config --libs --cflags sbpl` :

```
-I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lsbpl
```

and the output of `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH pkg-config --libs --cflags sbpl` :

```
-I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lsbpl
```

> And this is with the
> tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg fork?

Yes.. this is with the `tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg` fork!

> Can you make sure those two lines
> (with find_library(..)) are present in
> the CMakeLists.txt of your
> sbpl_lattice_planner?

and yes, `CMakeLists.txt` of `sbpl_lattice_planner` has following lines:

```
find_library(SBPL_LIBRARY NAMES sbpl PATHS ${SBPL_LIBRARY_DIRS} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)  
set(SBPL_LIBRARIES ${SBPL_LIBRARY})
```

and the output after adding `message("SBPL_LIBRARIES: ${SBPL_LIBRARIES}")`  is:

```
SBPL_LIBRARIES: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libsbpl.so
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217299/problem-installing-sbpl-from-source-in-ros-indigo/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-09-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> All the commands ran successfully but when I do `roscd sbpl` after it, the output is : `roscd: No such package/stack 'sbpl'` . Does anyone have any idea why is it still not able to find sbpl and what am I doing wrong?

Judging by the contents of the repository you linked, I'd say SBPL is not a catkin/rosbuild package, but a regular CMake package. The way you built and installed it also seems to point in that direction.

As such, you cannot `roscd` to it, as that only works with ROS packages.

---

Edit:

> Also, I tried installing and using SBPL as a ROS package but that does not seem to be working

> [..]

> Does anyone have any idea why is it still not able to find sbpl and what am I doing wrong?

Yes: SBPL is *still* not a ROS package. You adding it to your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and trying to build it using `rosmake` does not change that.

Afaict, SBPL is not meant to be a ROS package. It's used as a system dependency (see [CMakeLists.txt - lines 13 to 15](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental/blob/198fc7ffd4dedf7af1e01857711249118476fc1d/sbpl_lattice_planner/CMakeLists.txt#L13-L15) of `sbpl_lattice_planner`).

---

Edit 2:

> It looks like sbpl_lattice_planner is not able to find the necessary sbpl library and is throwing an error and hence its not able to run.

I'm pretty certain it should've worked after you `sudo make install`ed your version of SBPL and then tried to build `sbpl_lattice_planner` from source (PkgConfig should've picked up your customised version, *if* you got the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` setup correctly).

But looking at one of the forks (the [tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/sbpl_lattice_planner) one) recommended to you in your [other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/208515/sbpl_lattice_planner-in-ros-indigo/) about `sbpl_lattice_planner`, it could also be that CMake needs a little help determining the correct path to `libsbpl.so` (from [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/sbpl_lattice_planner/blob/b7d9fd3e3a7621f974c6de50429cc3df544d36cb/CMakeLists.txt#L16-L17)):

```
[..]
find_library(SBPL_LIBRARY NAMES sbpl PATHS ${SBPL_LIBRARY_DIRS} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
set(SBPL_LIBRARIES ${SBPL_LIBRARY})
[..]
```

This snippet adds the full path to `libsbpl.so`, which then gets linked later on. Any reason you are not using this fork?

Btw: the error is not 'thrown' by `sbpl_lattice_planner`, but is *reported* by `make`. It just can't resolve the dependency on `libsbpl.so` needed for the `sbpl_lattice_planner` target.

---

Edit 3:

> @gvdhoorn: I am using the fork you mentioned.

That would've nice to know before we started all this. Why did you link to the original `sbpl` repository then in your question?

> My PKG_CONFIG_PATH is:

> ```
> /home/naman/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/home/naman/catkin_ws/devel/lib/x86_64-linux gnu/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig
> ```

> Therefore, sbpl_lattice_planner looks for `libsbpl.so` in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib` and is not able to find it.

No. `make` can't find the library, `sbpl_lattice_planner` has not even been built yet. It is not involved here at all.

Please add the output of `pkg-config --libs --cflags sbpl` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH pkg-config --libs --cflags sbpl` to your question. Both times after you've sourced your workspace.

> Once, I build sbpl as mentioned above, it installs `libsbpl.so` in `/usr/local/lib` and `sbpl.pc` in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` but its not in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH and therefore its not able to find the required files BUT even if I add `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` to PKG_CONFIG_PATH, it still looks for the file in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib` and hence gives the same error as mentioned above which is really confusing for me.

And this is with the `tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg` fork? Can you make sure those two lines (with `find_library(..)`) are present in the `CMakeLists.txt` of your `sbpl_lattice_planner`? Can you add:

```
message("SBPL_LIBRARIES: ${SBPL_LIBRARIES}")
```

right before the `# Generate messages` line and add the output of this in a new run of `catkin_make` to your question?

---

Edit 4:

> and the output of `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH pkg-config --libs --cflags sbpl`:

> ```
> -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lsbpl
> ```

I'm guessing you don't have `ros-indigo-sbpl` installed on that system?

Just to be sure: are you trying to cross-compile? Or are you building on your Jetson board itself?

As to the rest: I cannot reproduce this on my system. I've installed SBPL from the repository you linked (installs into `/usr/local`), then made sure there is a `sbpl.pc` in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`.

Running `catkin_make` in a freshly created catkin workspace with just `sbpl_lattice_planner` in it returns the correct paths (ie: cmake finds sbpl in the right place). The planner pkg builds successfully.

The only thing that requires some care is when the system does have the ROS provided `ros-indigo-sbpl` installed. As `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is set to `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig`, `pkg-config` will ignore the `sbpl.pc` in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. Explicitly setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to have the `/usr/local` location first resolves this, and the from-source compiled SBPL will be found again.

In summary, this gets me a working `sbpl_lattice_planner`:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/sbpl_ws/src
cd /tmp/sbpl_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/sbpl_lattice_planner.git

cd /tmp/sbpl_ws
git clone https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl.git
# create build dir, config, make, sudo make install
# sbpl is now installed in '/usr/local'

source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

catkin_make

# output here is (among other things)
SBPL_LIBRARIES: /usr/local/lib/libsbpl.so
SBPL_LIBRARY_DIRS: /usr/local/lib
SBPL_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/include
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-09-08**:
Thanks for the answer @gvdhoorn! I have updated my original question where I tried installing SBPL as a  ROS Package.

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-09-23**:
@gvdhoorn! Yeah.. When I removed the build and the devel folder from my workspace and built all the packages including sbpl again, everything seems to be working. Thanks a lot! :)

**Comment by [non-conventional_stuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/27818/non-conventional_stuff/) on 2016-09-02**:
Hello Sir,
Installed sbpl at /usr/local
I did the following :
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

I get the following error on $roslaunch sbpl_lattice_planner move_base_sbpl_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch
ResourceNotFound : sbpl